# Removing duplicates using regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi i am trying to remove the duplicates from a string. Ex:

```
"Q. no. -320/2/2, Road no 25, Adityapur, Transport colony,  ADITYAPUR"
```

In the above example `"Adityapur"` is repeated twice. So i want to remove it. How can i do that using regex.

I am using this regex:

```
re.sub(r'\b(\w+)( \1\b)+', r'\1', s)
```

but it is removing all the duplicate letters also.

Comment: Why are you using regex for this?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work at all. `s = "Q. no. -320/2/2, Road no 25, Adityapur, Transport colony,  ADITYAPUR" ; print(re.sub(r'\b(\w+)( \1\b)+', r'\1', s) == s) ; True`

Comment: You could extract what you need with `re.findall` (e.g.: only words) then if you have matches you can wrap the resulting list with `set` which will only keep unique values (does not maintain order, but you can easily work around that if you need to preserve order).

Comment: If you are asking to replace just one word then I guess you know the solution. But if such string are repeated then provide more data and specify pattern.

Comment: In addition to "Adityapur", "no" is also duplicated, so is "2". Should each of these duplicates also be removed? If not how do you differentiate between them? Also, which instance of the duplicate should be removed? Finally, what if there is more than 2 instances of the same word?

Answer (score 0):

regex version:

```
import re
s = "Q. no. -320/2/2, Road no 25, Adityapur, Transport colony,  ADITYAPUR"
s = s.lower()
re.split('; |, ',str)
m = [x.strip() for x in m]

sen = []
temp = []
for x in m:
    if x not in sen:
        sen.append(x)

free = ' '.join(sen)
print(free)
```

Comment: AG INDUSTRIES BAWAL PVT LTD. PLOT NO 97-102, BAWAL INDUSTRIAL AREA, SEC-6, BAWAL, DIST-REWARI , bawal industrial area, rewari, haryana . i am not able to remove the duplicates for this address by using your code

Comment: are not your delimiter constant?

Comment: but it is not removing any duplicates for the above commented address